# Listview  checkbox проблема

Tags: checkbox, android, listview, java

Создал costum listview, содержащий фото, названия группы и checkbox. При выборе checkbox и при прокрутке checkbox выделения переходят произвольно. Как решить данную проблему?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPhoto" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"/>
    <LinearLayout

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" android:baselineAligned="false" android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textName" android:layout_weight="1.00"/>

        <CheckBox

                android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


import tat.ilmir.myapplicationnew.appnew.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ilmir4400 on 12/6/14.
 */
public class ListViewGroupsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Groups> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;

    public ListViewGroupsAdapter(Context context, List<Groups> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_groups, parent, false);
        }
        final Groups groups = getGroups(position);
        TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);


        textName.setText(groups.getName());

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto); //вьюха, где будет отображать картинку
        String imageUrl = groups.getPhoto();//... // URL картинки (н-р: "http://site.com/image.png", "file:///mnt/sdcard/img/image.jpg")

        ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Получили экземпляр
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context)); // Проинициализировали конфигом по умолчанию
        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView);

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context, Boolean.parseBoolean("UniversalImageLoader/Cache"));

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // width, height
//                .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75) // width, height, compress format, quality
                .threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024)) // 2 Mb
                .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
//                .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(5 * 1000, 30 * 1000)) // connectTimeout (5 s), readTimeout (30 s)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
//                .enableLogging()
                .build();

        return view;
    }

    private Groups getGroups(int position) {
        return (Groups) getItem(position);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_groups, parent, false);
    }
    Groups groups = getGroups(position);
    TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textName);
    ImageView imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    // пишем позицию
    checkBox.setTag(position);
    // заполняем данными из товаров: в корзине или нет
    checkBox.setChecked(groups.box);
....}
```

// обработчик для чекбоксов

```
OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
        // меняем данные товара (в корзине или нет)
        getGroups((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
    }
};
```